# Oracle SQL PIVOT with multiple sum columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table with like this...

```
create table my_table_for_pivot (month date, country varchar2(40),metric1, metric2);

insert into my_table_for_pivot(month, country, metric1, metric2) values ('01-jan-2013', 'usa','100','75');
insert into my_table_for_pivot(month, country, metric1, metric2) values ('01-jan-2013', 'argentina','24','10');
insert into my_table_for_pivot(month, country, metric1, metric2) values ('01-mar-2013', 'brazil','60','15');
insert into my_table_for_pivot(month, country, metric1, metric2) values ('01-feb-2013', 'usa','111','90');
insert into my_table_for_pivot(month, country, metric1, metric2) values ('01-feb-2013', 'argentina','15','20');
insert into my_table_for_pivot(month, country, metric1, metric2) values ('01-feb-2013', 'brazil','75','30');
insert into my_table_for_pivot(month, country, metric1, metric2) values ('01-mar-2013', 'usa','105','70');
insert into my_table_for_pivot(month, country, metric1, metric2) values ('01-mar-2013', 'argentina','27','23');
insert into my_table_for_pivot(month, country, metric1, metric2) values ('01-mar-2013', 'brazil','53,'28');
```

My goal is to pivot the table so that the months are along the column headers, but each metric is listed on its own row.  My users will be selecting country in a dropdown and the result will recalculate based on the item dropdown (like :p20_country)  The resultant table would look someting like this...

users choose usa

```
Metric  jan13  feb13 mar13
metric1 100     111   105
metric2 75      90    70
```

my pivot attempts have not worked as I don;t know how to get the metric name on the row level.

```
select *
from (
select
country,
month,
metric1,
metric2
from my_table_for_pivot)
pivot (
sum(metric1) as mo1,sum(metric2) as mo2 for month IN
('01-JAN-14' AS JAN_14,
 '01-FEB-14' AS FEB_14,
 '01-MAR-14' AS MAR_14))
where country = 'usa'
;
```

I did try to use SQLfiddle but could not get to work for this example..would very much appreciate any help or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are more optimal ways to write this query, but this is one way; merge the metric values into a single column and add a name column which is not mentioned in the pivot part. This will create a row per name;

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT country, month, metric1 metric, 'metric1' metric_name
  FROM my_table_for_pivot
  UNION ALL
  SELECT country, month, metric2 metric, 'metric2' metric_name
  FROM my_table_for_pivot
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(metric) as month for month IN
('01-JAN-2013' AS JAN_13,
 '01-FEB-2013' AS FEB_13,
 '01-MAR-2013' AS MAR_13))
WHERE country = 'usa'
;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/252f4/1).

Comment: That is really awesome!!! Really appreciate the help!  I have to say also that Stackoverflow the best!

Comment: I've updated my query and it runs great in SQL dev, but as soon as I run it in an APEX classic report it only returns nulls for months.  Any ideas why this must be?  I do get the country and metric1 and metric2 but all the values are null in APEX.